# Spacy Python entity Recognition add to existing Model

Tags: python, spacy

Hello Developers hope you are doing well I am kind of struggling with an issue and looking for help from the community

```
import spacy
import json


nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
text = "Apple and Facebook and jobtarget  looking at buying U.K. ie London  startup for $1 billion and hiring more software engineer's  lets see "

entity = [
    {
        "word":ent.text,
        "startIndex":ent.start_char,
        "endIndex":ent.end_char,
        "label": ent.label_
    }
    
     for ent in nlp(text).ents 
]

print(entity)
```

Following code Works great no issue so far print the results :D so far happy

```
[{'word': 'Apple', 'startIndex': 0, 'endIndex': 5, 'label': 'ORG'}, {'word': 'Facebook', 'startIndex': 10, 'endIndex': 18, 'label': 'ORG'}, {'word': 'U.K.', 'startIndex': 52, 'endIndex': 56, 'label': 'GPE'}, {'word': 'London', 'startIndex': 60, 'endIndex': 66, 'label': 'GPE'}, {'word': '$1 billion', 'startIndex': 80, 'endIndex': 90, 'label': 'MONEY'}]
```

following is output now i already went through documentation of spacy on how to train the custom model creating a new model and training your entity well thats is also fine works great

however what I want to do with the existing model for given text

```
text = "Apple and Facebook and abcdcompany looking at buying U.K. ie London  startup for $1 billion and hiring more software engineer's  lets see"
```

i want to add abcdcompany to ORG NER here is my code to do that

```
import warnings


nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
nlp.pipe_names
ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")

ner.add_label('TITLE')


TRAIN_DATA = [



('Apple and Facebook and companyabcd  looking at buying U.K. ie London  startup for $1 billion and hiring more software engineer lets see', {'entities': [(23, 34, 'ORG')]}), 
("I like London and Berlin.", {"entities": [(7, 13, "LOC"), (18, 24, "LOC")]}),

]


pipe_exceptions = ["ner", "trf_wordpiecer", "trf_tok2vec"]
other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe not in pipe_exceptions]
move_names = list(ner.move_names)


with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes), warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("once", category=UserWarning, module='spacy')
    sizes = compounding(1.0, 4.0, 1.001)
    
    for itn in range(10):
        
        random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
        batches = minibatch(TRAIN_DATA, size=sizes)
        losses = {}
        for batch in batches:
            texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
            nlp.update(texts, annotations, sgd=optimizer, drop=0.35, losses=losses)
        print("Losses", losses)

test_text = "Apple and Facebook and companyabcd  looking at buying U.K. ie London  startup for $1 billion and hiring more software engineer  lets se"
doc = nlp(test_text)
print("Entities in '%s'" % test_text)
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.label_, ent.text)
```

[image]

However, is not recognizing the companyabcd as ORG
NOTE: I don't want to create a blank model and train and save I want to add things to the existing model.

Answer (score 0):

You've run into a unrelated bug caused by adding new labels. Take out this line and this example will work as expected:

```py
ner.add_label('TITLE')
```

Note that in your example the model will learn "companyabcd" and may forget "Apple", "Facebook", "U.K.", "London", and/or "$1 billion" because you didn't label them in your training example. If they're not labeled, the model learns that they **aren't** entities. See: https://spacy.io/usage/training#ner

---

If you do want to add new labels, a workaround is to save and reload the model first before training:

```py
nlp.to_disk("/path/to/model")
nlp = spacy.load("/path/to/model")
ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")
```

Comment: First of all thank you for taking out time to review issue 
well i dont want my model to foget facebook and apple as you mentioned you would label them well in the situation  model already understand facebook and apple i dont want the model to forget when i am training for companyabcd its forgetiing it 

ru saying before training i save the model to disk and load again and train on that and the again save ? 


load spacy web sm model 
do save to Disk 
train 
save to DIsk ?

is that correct ?

Comment: If you're not adding new labels like `TITLE`, you can skip the reloading step. You need to annotate all existing entities in your training data examples in order not to forget "Facebook", etc.